# How to get started with open source contribution?

Tags: github, open-source

How can a beginner get started with open source contributions ,
Let says that the beginner have a basic knowledge of programming.

I tried searching on youtube and google , and i didn't find any optimistic path related to it .

If anyone can help me , how can i get started with open source .

I have the knowledge of medium level DSA and good in C++ lang. and ,also knows the basic of java, python!!

Answer (score 0):

1. Explore existing open-source projects that are related to the stack you are familiar with.
2. Choose a project that aligns with your interest.
3. Read the contribution guidelines.
4. Fork the repository so that you have a copy of it. Gives you complete freedom. However, you definitely have to make sure that there are only specific changes before submitting.
5. Set up your own environment and get started.
6. Don't forget to test your changes before submitting a pull request.
7. If there's any feedback on your contribution, take it positively and improve your work accordingly.

Good luck!

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow. It looks like it's been a while since you've posted and may not be aware of the latest policies since your answer appears likely to have been entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). As a heads-up, [posting of AI-generated content is not permitted on Stack Overflow](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831).

If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify quality issues.

Comment: It's especially likely to be AI-based considering how similar it is (albeit abbreviated) when compared with the other answer here that was posted after yours (also seemingly from AI).

Comment: This anser seems to be generated or copied from AI based tools like chatGpt or google bard.